# Using variable in "IN" function of SQL query in R

Tags: r

I am having a variable x which contains 20000 IDs. I want to write a sql query like,

```
select * from tablename where ID in x;
```

I am trying to implement this in R where I can get the values only for IDs in x variable. The following is my try,

```
dbSendQuery(mydb, "select * from tablename where ID in ('$x') ")
```

I am not getting any error while trying this. But it is returning 0 values.

Next tried using

```
sprintf("select * from tablename where ID in %s",x)
```

But this is creating 20000 individual queries which could prove costly in DB.

Can anybody suggest me a way to write a command, which would loop through IDs in x and save to a Dataframe in R in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about pasting it:

```
dbSendQuery(mydb, paste("select * from tablename where ID in (", paste(x, collapse = ","), ")"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the codes in the actual string.  Here is how I would do it with `gsub`

```
x <- LETTERS[1:3]

sql <- "select * from tablename where ID in X_ID_CODES "

x_codes <- paste0("('", paste(x, collapse="','"), "')")

sql <- gsub("X_ID_CODES", x_codes, sql)

# see new output
cat(sql)
select * from tablename where ID in ('A','B','C')  


# then submit the query
#dbSendQuery(mydb, sql)
```

Comment: Both the codes are working fine. Since that was in a single line and easier way, I accepted that. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @haimen whatever your preference.  Keep this in mind, however, if you begin to develop more complex queries that need to be dynamic.  Those single line statements can get pretty unwieldy.